# SUMIFS OR criterion

Tags: excel, sum

I'm working with rainfall precipitation data and I want to find the total rainfall for the months of April, May, June, July for each year.  My columns are as follows:

A: rainfall for each day

B: month

C: year

D: day

E: number indicating the reliability of the rainfall observation (0,1,2 or 9)

I want to exclude the unreliable observations.  So to find the total rainfall for those four months in 1923, for example, would the following be correct?

SUMIFS(A1:A100,B1:B100,{"4","5","6","7"},C1:C100,"1923",E1:E100,"<>9")

Comment: What is considered unreliable? Just 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current formula returns an array. For example, if you highlight your formula and press the F9 key, you will see that your formula is returning four different values.  For the correct result, you are going to need to wrap your formula with a SUM function.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(A1:A100,B1:B100,{"4","5","6","7"},C1:C100,"1923",E1:E100,"<>9"))
```